# Return the largest number in an array in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I've been trying to return the largest number in an array, but I keep getting 13. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    Dim maxage As Integer = 0
    Dim ageList() As Integer = {12, 13, 18, 11, 5, 3}
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(ageList)
        If i > maxage Then
            maxage = ageList(i)
        End If
    Next i
    Console.WriteLine(maxage)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: you might try **if ageList(i) > maxage** then

Comment: It looks like this is [VB.NET] not [VBA]. In VB.NET you can also do `{12, 13, 18, 11, 5, 3}.Max` or `ageList.Max`. In VBA you can use `WorksheetFunction.Max(ageList)`.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing 'i' to 'maxage' instead of the element in the array.

```
Dim maxage As Integer = 0
Dim ageList() As Integer = {12, 13, 18, 11, 5, 3}
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To UBound(ageList)
    If ageList(i) > maxage Then
        maxage = ageList(i)
    End If
Next i
Console.WriteLine(maxage)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Yep. Since `maxage` starts at `0`, `i` will become greater than `maxage` when it is `1`. The value at index `1` is `13`, so `maxage` is set to `13`. `i` will never be greater than `maxage` again. Also, I have a nephew named Leviticus. There can't be too many in the world with that name ;)